# adding countries to google.visualization.DataTable() using a loop

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Hi I would like to make a world map with all the countries in it and eventually let it keep track from where people made a transaction. But first I have trouble importing the countries. I've decided to use an for-loop to add the raw data to the country column but it does not work out quite well for me. I get to see nothing at all and i was wondering what i am doing wrong here...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">

</script><script type="text/javascript">
      //google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Åland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua And Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia, Plurinational State Of", "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius And Saba", "Bosnia And Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Côte D'ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island And Mcdonald Islands", "Holy See (vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Republic Of", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle Of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic Of", "Korea, Republic Of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States Of", "Moldova, Republic Of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestine, State Of", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Réunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Barthélemy", "Saint Helena, Ascension And Tristan Da Cunha", "Saint Kitts And Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Martin (french Part)", "Saint Pierre And Miquelon", "Saint Vincent And The Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Sint Maarten (dutch Part)", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard And Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province Of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic Of", "Thailand", "Timor-leste", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad And Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic Of", "Viet Nam", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.s.", "Wallis And Futuna", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
                                        data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
                                        data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
                                        for(i = 0; i < countries .length; i++)
                                        data.addRow([countries[i]]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

        var options = {
            chartArea:{width:'100%',height:'100%'},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%;"><img alt="" /></div>
```

Any help/feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*recommended* changes to the code posted in the question...

1. uncomment `google.charts.load` statement
2. add `callback` to `load` statement
3. when creating a DataTable, must use the `new` keyword
   `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  // <-- 'new' was missing`
4. when adding rows --> `data.addRow` -- must provide a value for each column
   if no value, use `null`
   this line was missing a value for the second column --> `'Transactions'`
   `data.addRow([countries[i], null]);  // <-- added 'null' for second column`
5. don't use `style` attribute on elements --> `<div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%;">`
6. use an empty `div`
   `<div id="regions_div"></div>`
   -- vs. --
   `<div id="regions_div"><img alt="" /></div>`

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages: ['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Åland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua And Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia, Plurinational State Of", "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius And Saba", "Bosnia And Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Côte D'ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island And Mcdonald Islands", "Holy See (vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Republic Of", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle Of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic Of", "Korea, Republic Of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States Of", "Moldova, Republic Of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestine, State Of", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Réunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Barthélemy", "Saint Helena, Ascension And Tristan Da Cunha", "Saint Kitts And Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Martin (french Part)", "Saint Pierre And Miquelon", "Saint Vincent And The Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Sint Maarten (dutch Part)", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard And Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province Of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic Of", "Thailand", "Timor-leste", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad And Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic Of", "Viet Nam", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.s.", "Wallis And Futuna", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
  for(i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([countries[i], null]);
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 600
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```